# Accessing remote devices with dynamic IP

Tags: dynamic, dns, ip-address

I need to access about 15 devices remotely with a software in a single server.

All these devices are connected to the internet through modems and I can access them, privided I have the modem IP. But most of these modems have dynamic IPs that usually changes more than once a week for various reasons.

I tried using dynamic DNS, but it doesn't work because the software accepts only IPs in the format XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX in its configuration.

Is it possible to configure a DNS server (or any other tool) to point to one of my dynamic DNS when asked for a specific IP address in my local network? I was going to try it but my Windows server fails to install the DNS server role, so I want to know if I should even bother solving this other problem.

In other words I want to do this: **local IP -> global name address -> global IP address**

Example: **192.168.1.100 -> dynamic.name.com -> 200.100.10.27**

Comment: Is this a problem with some specific software or is programming involved? Most languages allow the coder to resolve a DNS address into an IP address.

Comment: It's a specific software. There's really not much I can do with it.

Comment: In that case, either [Super User](http://superuser.com/about) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about) StackExchange sites probably fit your question better.